# Dividing circles into arcs.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

There are $2022$ points on a circle. These points are distributed uniformly (distance between $2$ neighbor points is the same) and this circle is divided into arcs where the endpoints of these arcs are points on the circle such that,

(i) No two arcs overlap.

(ii)  The lengths of arcs is pairwise different.

(iii)  The smallest arc doesn't intersect with the biggest arc i.e they don’t share the same endpoint.

Let $k$ be the maximal number of arcs we can put in the circle. Find $k$ for $2022$ points.

So the first thing I did is try small cases, here is what I found
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline n & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\ \hline k & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ \hline  \end{array}

Where $n$ is the number of points on the circle.
The numbers are weird ; they kind of repeat and then jump by $1$ and actually I noticed that $k$ is exactly the biggest arc in the circle but I have no way to prove this. I have an idea that I'm not sure of, we can transform this problem into something like that $$n=(2+1+3+4+...+k)+r$$
Where $0\le r\le k$ and notice that I put $2$ first intead of $1$ so that we can avoid the biggest arc intersecting with the smallest arc.

Comment: Why would you state (iii) when (i) seems to cover it? It hints that there might be a problem with the formulation of the question, or maybe a translation issue. Are the arc endpoints always one of the 2022 points?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it seems that two arcs having the same endpoints but nothing else in common counts as an intersection, but not as an overlap. So two arcs may intersect (may share an endpoint), but not the smallest one with the biggest one.

Comment: So, 'intersect' and 'overlap' mean different things? Then it is highly unclear what the two terms mean. In any event, it is best to let OP clarify what is meant, rather than guessing. @Thomas

Comment: I find the word "divide" already loosely implies that the arcs are a partition, which would mean the arcs don't overlap in the sense that I would use the word 'overlap.'

Comment: If I were to try to give a meaning to this problem, this seems to be mostly about integer partitions into distinct values, except when $k<4.$ If $1+2+\dots+k>2022,$ there is certainly no answer. If $k>3$ nd $f(k)=1+2+\dots +k\leq 2022$ we can divide the circle into $k$ arcs of length $1,2,\dots,k-1,k,$ at least in some order. Say, $1,2,k,3,\dots,k-1.$

Comment: @Thomas That's true.

Comment: You should get $k=3$ for $n=7.$ Specifically, arcs of length $1,2,3$ satisfies your condition, unless I am missing something. There is a gap of length $1$ between the arcs of length $3$ and $1.$

Comment: Yes I missed that @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if we let the lengths of the arcs to be $a_1<\cdots <a_k$, then we have that $a_1+\cdots+a_k \leq 2022$. Moreover, since $a_i<a_{j}$  for appropriate $i<j$, if we let $b_i=a_i-i$, then $b_i\leq b_j$ for $i<j$.

The question then just boils down to the existence of a non-negative integer solution to $x_1+\cdots+x_k\leq 2022-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ such that $x_i\leq x_j$ for $i<j$. Whenever, there is a solution to $x_1+\cdots+x_k\leq 2022-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, we can just put it in non-decreasing order and we can get such a required solution.

A solution to $x_1+\cdots+x_k\leq 2022-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ exists whenever the RHS is non-negative, therefore, we want the largest $k$ such $2022-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\geq 0$.

Since $2016=\frac{63\times 64}{2}$, $k$ must be $63$.

As for the actual lengths, take a partition of $6$, say $3+1+1+1$. Now, add them to $63,62,61,60$ respectively to get $1+2+\cdots+59+61+62+63+66=2022$

Comment: I don't think $a_1+...+a_k=2022$ is true, since there can be a leftover arc that has a length $\le a_k$ so we can't count it.

Comment: I think the changes I've made should be enough.

Comment: In general, when $k<4$ you have to worry a little about the third condition, which is why this alone doesn't work for $n=3,4,6.$

Comment: I figured but since the question was for 2022, I didn't include it. I should have.

Answer (score 1):

Because the sums of $k$ distinct positive integers is at least $1+2+\cdots+k=\frac{k(k+1)}2,$ if $\frac{k(k+1)}2>2022,$ you certainly can't solve it.

So you need $$\frac{k(k+1)}2\leq n$$

Multiplying by $8$ and adding one, we see this is equivalent to $(2k+1)^2\leq 8n+1$ or: $$k\leq\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}2.\tag1$$

But if $k>3,$ we can use arcs of minimal lengths in circular order: $1,2,k,3,\dots,k-1,$ to satisfy the third condition.

(When $k\leq 3,$ the third condition makes it harder, which is why the largest such $k$ doesn't work form $n=3,4,6.$)

So you need the largest $k$ such is: $$\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8\cdot2022+1}-1}2\right\rfloor=63$$

We can actually use the whole circle, by replacing the $63$ arc with the remaining length, $69.$ So you get:

$$1+2+69+3+4+\cdots+62=2022.$$