# Dividing circles into arcs...Again.

Tags: combinatorics

This is a slightly different version of my previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593088/dividing-circles-into-arcs) which asks to find the maximum value of the number of arcs, for completeness I will include the question here but I will change two conditions (namely, the first and the third).

There are $2022$ points on a circle. These points are distributed uniformly (i.e. distance between $2$ neighbor points is the same) and this circle is divided into arcs where the endpoints of these arcs are the points on the circle such that,

$\color{red} {\text{(i) No arc is completely included in another}}$

(ii)  The lengths of arcs is pairwise different.

(iii)  The smallest arc and the biggest $\color{red}{\text{do not overlap}}$, and they don’t share the same endpoint.

$k_n$ is the maximum number of arcs we can put on a circle with $n$ points, find $k$ of $2022$.

Let's associate every point with a number from $1$ to $2022$ (in order) and let $arc(a,b)$ denote the arc from point $a$ to point $b$ . Now it is easy to show $k=1011$ works like this, $$arc(1,2), arc(2,4), arc(3,6),...,arc(1011,2022).$$ However I have no idea how to prove $k<1012$ .

Answer (score 1):

One readily shows $k_2=1$ and $k_3=1$. Suppose $n>3$. Among all valid constellations with $k_n$ arcs and $n$ points, consider one of minimal total length.

Let $d$ be the length of the shortest arc. Suppose $d>1$. If we shorten every arc $(a,b)\to(a,b+1-d)$ (and $(a,b)\to(a,b+1-d+n)$ if $b+1-d\le0$), we obtain a valid configuration of shorter length, contradiction.

Hence, the shortest arc has length $1$, wlog it is $(n-1,n)$. Remove points $n$ and $n-1$ and change any affected arc $(a,n-1)\to(a,1)$ and $(n,b)\to(n-2,b)$ of same length. This gives us one less arc with two less points. Just in case this new constellation breaks (iii), note that this can be mended by shortening every arc at its right end as in the preceding paragraph. We conclude $k_{n-2}\ge k_n-1$.

Then by induction,
$$k_n\le\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: Isn't it possible that condition (iii) is broken when we're doing the shortening process? For example, if we have only two arcs $(1, 3)$ and $(2, 5)$, the process will give us $(1, \color{red}2)$ and $(\color{red}2, 4)$ which makes the two arcs have a common endpoint.

Comment: With $n = 7$, the four arcs $(7, 2)$, $(1, 4)$, $(2, 6)$, $(3, 1)$ should satisfy the requirements given in the problem. This contradicts your $k_n \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ inequality. A diagram of the arcs: https://imgur.com/a/sAoXmA6

Comment: There's also another counterexample that includes an arc of length $1$: https://imgur.com/a/GyR5g6N. Here, $n = 9$ and the five arcs are $(1, 2)$, $(2, 4)$, $(7, 1)$, $(3, 7)$, and $(4, 9)$.

Comment: @VTand I'm sorry I mistakenly said that the smallest arc and the shortest don't share the same endpoints

Comment: @VTand What I meant is that they don't overlap. So I think Hagen's answer is still correct.

Comment: @PNT Unless I misunderstood the problem, I think my counterexample for $n = 9$ still holds? The arc of length $1$ is at $(1, 2)$, while the arc of length $5$ is at $(4, 9)$.

Comment: @VTand Yes it is true.